# VBA - Assign Class to Object With Another Class

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to set an object as a class that isn't its own class?

For instance, if I have a class of `Class_Fruit` and a class of `Class_Apple`, is there any way to do:

```vb
Dim appleClass as Class_Fruit
Set appleClass = New Class_Apple
```

Like what you can do in other languages like Java

I suspect it's not possible, because VBA is just not built to work like that and it doesn't have inheritance, but I wanted to ask to make sure.

I've had a look around but not been able to find a definitive answer, so I figured I should ask before I waste any more time trying to get it to work. I'm RELATIVELY new to Class objects in VBA, and pretty much all I can find about them is how to build them, not the further levels of functionality that they might have.

I have a workaround I can use if this isn't possible, but doing this would be much easier if there is any way to do it at all.

Comment: So if your `Class_Fruit` is an interface and your `Class_Apple` has `Implements Class_Fruit`, then you can write code exactly as you've shown.

Comment: Ah! Fantastic, thank you!

Apologies if this is a duplicate of another question someone asked, I did look but I couldn't find anything